# Use a variable in Typoscript "select"

Tags: select, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I try to get an author of a Typo3 site and after this i try to fill a Typo3 select (typoscript) with the resulting ID.
Its somehow working, but i can not use the lib oder variable as datasource of another select

I tryed to play arround with LOAD_REGISTER or marker. But i think it has to be a way to use a select result or another "lib" result in a select.

Here is my code:

```
// Returns succsessfully "neuz8" and i can use this in fluid
lib.author = TEXT
lib.author.data = page:author

lib.Authornavigation = CONTENT
lib.Authornavigation {
    stdWrap.required = 1
    table = be_users
    select {
        uidInList = 0
        pidInList = root
        selectFields = be_users.uid as id, be_users.realName as rn, be_users.profile_pid as prid
        where = be_users.profile_pid != '0'
        andWhere =  be_users.realName={lib.author} // Is not working, why?
        // I tryed: combinations of andWhere.data or lib.author.data, 
        // with and without {}, 
        // with LOAD_REGISTER, 
        // with "markers", 

        //andWhere =  be_users.realName='neuz8' < this works and returns "39", the correct ID
        andWhere.wrap =
        markers {
            //author.data = {page:author}
        }
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = prid
        10.wrap2  =  ###SPLITTER### |
    }
    stdWrap.split {
        token = ###SPLITTER###
        cObjNum = 1 |*| 2 |*| 1
        1.current = 1
        2.current = 1
        2.wrap = |,
    }
}
```

Comment: This site is English-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

replace

```
// andWhere =  be_users.realName={lib.author} // Is not working, why?
```

with

```
andWhere = be_users.realName= 
andWhere.postCObject < temp.author
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Can you explain how i am able to find out things like that by myself?

Comment: :D eh - good point - on my side, that's just an awful long track record of typoscript experience the hard way - and lots of curiosity and patience...

Answer (score 0):

You can try select.markers:

```
page.60 = CONTENT
page.60 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList = 73
    where = header != ###whatever###
    orderBy = ###sortfield###
    markers {
      whatever.data = GP:first
      sortfield.value = sor
      sortfield.wrap = |ting
    }
  }
}
```

[Docs » Functions » select](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select/Index.html) (see part markers)